# Difference between sshd-keygen and ssh-keygen

Tags: linux, centos, ssh, sshd

I understand that ssh-keygen is used to generate private and public keys.
But what is the use of sshd-keygen?

I don't find a man page or doc, hence there is no documentation about the use of sshd-keygen.

```
[root@intel-chiefriver-02 ~]# whereis sshd-keygen
sshd-keygen: /usr/sbin/sshd-keygen
[root@intel-chiefriver-02 ~]# cat /etc/redhat-release 
CentOS Linux release 7.6.1810 (Core)
```

Comment: Where do you find `sshd-keygen`? It isn't part of the ordinary OpenSSH distribution.

Comment: @Kusalananda it is there by-default in CentOS 7. Added more info about the host info in question section.

Comment: @smc, what's your version of the openssh-server rpm?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There's `/usr/libexec/openssh/sshd-keygen` in Fedora's [openssh-server-7.9p1-5.fc30.x86_64.rpm](https://fedora.pkgs.org/30/fedora-x86_64/openssh-server-7.9p1-5.fc30.x86_64.rpm.html). It's a script to create the host keys. There's a systemd service that goes with it, `sshd-keygen@.service`.

The service checks if a particular host key doesn't exist, and runs the script which just calls `ssh-keygen` to create them. So, if the host keys don't exist or get deleted, they're regenerated the next time they're needed.

There's also mentions of `sshd-keygen` in the Fedora wiki, in [Changes/Remove slogin and sshd-keygen](https://fedoraproject.org/wiki/Changes/Remove_slogin_and_sshd-keygen).

It mentions removing "sshd-keygen, a legacy Fedora init script" (and replace it with a proper systemd service) and mentions "Applications/services that needs to make sure that ssh host keys are available".

Yours might be a different implementation, but I suppose it's safe to say that it's for the same purpose.

Answer (score 1):

The SSH server itself has a key that it uses to identify itself to clients.  This is to prevent man-in-the-middle attacks, etc.  Also why you'll see something like

```
The authenticity of host '[foo.example.com]:22 ([10.0.2.15]:22)' can't be established.
ECDSA key fingerprint is SHA256:QOCUzNedwfepPHZ8JOn7xfGc1zQ8MmIohNCAE93jMEQ.
Are you sure you want to continue connecting (yes/no)?
```

The first time you connect to a remote host using ssh/scp/sftp

Actual files on the server for these keys should be under `/etc/ssh` -

```
ssh_host_dsa_key
ssh_host_dsa_key.pub
ssh_host_ecdsa_key
ssh_host_ecdsa_key.pub
ssh_host_ed25519_key
ssh_host_ed25519_key.pub
ssh_host_rsa_key
ssh_host_rsa_key.pub
```